# Faster iteration from 2M records

Tags: spring, java-8, stream

I have a `List<Map<String,String>>`.  and the list size is more than 2M.
I have one more `List<String>` whose size is 100.

In Map I have one key whose name is Business Unit.
I want to store only those data from `List<Map<String,String>>` whose Business Unit name present in the `List<String>`.

I want to use the Stream API of Java8. Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this requirement?

Comment: What have you tried? At least show your attempt using traditional loops. Also, `List<Map<String,String>>` should probably be just a `Map<String,String>`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i correctly understood your question. Did you try in this way:

```
@Test
public void testFilter() {
    try {
        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
        entities.parallelStream().forEach(entity -> {
            filtered.addAll(filterMap(entity));
        });
        logger.info("Keys {} dimensione {} filtered {} dimensione {}", keys, keys.size(), filtered, filtered.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Errore filter ", e);
    }
}
private List<String> filterMap(Map<String, String> entity) {
    return entity.keySet().parallelStream().filter(key -> keys.contains(key)).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: Did you have chance to test?